# Convert an Object[] to a Class<?> type at runtime?

Tags: java, arrays

I am having deep trouble and this is advanced Java (I am using Reflection API).

Two questions.

I have the following:

```
Class<?> clazz = String.class;
Object[] values = new Object[] { "abc", 50L, 20 } // notice the different types
```

I want to be able to Object[] -> clazz[]. Why am I asking this? Because the type of "clazz" is known at runtime via reflection.

```
// This works
String[] params = Arrays.asList(values).toArray(new String[values.length]);
// This doesnt
String[] params = Arrays.asList(values).toArray(new clazz[values.length]);
```

There's something else: Let's say that, at runtime, the class is java.lang.String. In the middle of the creating of the array above, how can I use String.valueOf() on each element?

How can I achieve this?

Thank you!

**Explaning more what I am trying to achieve**

I have this class:

```
class A {
    public void doIt(String... params) {
        ...
    }
}
```

And also this class:

```
class B {
    public void doIt(Long... params) {
        ...
    }
}
```

As you can see, **A** and **B** have the same method **doIt()** but with different argument types.

I the code below will fail:

```
Object[] params = {1, 2, 3};
new A().doIt(params);
```

With the exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to java.lang.String[]
```

So, what I am trying to do, is find the type of doIt()'s first param and I am trying to convert Object[] to String/Long/Integer[]. Is is more clear now?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Java is a statically typed language.  As such, the presumption is that most of the time both you and the compiler know the types of things you are working with.  If you want to be able to use a collection of things of varying types, then you may wish to use the Typesafe Heterogenous Container pattern instead of whatever it is that you're doing up there.

Comment: I don't think you know what you're doing.

Comment: (But if you want to create an array of a dynamic type, use ["reflections"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Class,%20int%29).)

Comment: You seem to be using a local variable, where a type name would make more sense.  Is that what you intended to do?

Comment: Ive updated the question to be more clear.

Comment: Perhaps what you want is for `A` and `B` to implement the same generic interface `Foo<T>`, with a method `doIt(T... params)`.  Then `A` implements `Foo<String>` and `B` implements `Foo<Long>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `Array.newInstance(clazz, values.length)`, that seems like it would be what you are trying to do. But I don't see how it helps you. If the elements of the array are of different types, and you end up with an array of Strings (albeit dynamically created), you won't be able to put all of the elements into it anyhow.

Comment: This is hardly any more clear I am afraid. You are trying to send ints into a method, that expects strings, that will fail regardless of however you create the array. Perhaps, it would help if you explained what it is that you are actually trying to achieve, rather than coming up with these weird examples. I bet, there is a better way to do what you need.

Comment: Even if the Array was only populated with Strings but typed as Object[], the type conversion would still fail. The key I am looking for is the conversion. When I know the type, its easy, when the type is mined from the target class at runtime, its get harder =/

Comment: The question is why you would create create an array of Object, if you are going to populate it with Strings.

Comment: It can be String/Long/Int/Boolean and the type is discovered in runtime.

Comment: How is the type discovered? What is your use case?

Comment: The type is discovered using Reflection, inspecting the methods parameter type.

Comment: Right. What I am saying is it **should not be** "discovered using Reflection". You are approaching it all wrong. If you have some strings, you don't need reflection to know that they are strings.

Comment: I actually solved it another way, without reflection. I forced every method parameter to be Object[], passed in the object array and then, inside the method, forced every single element of the array to be cast to String using String.valueOf(). I'll accept your answer because it partially answers the original question and I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

Skipping the comments on whether that kind of coding yields the best program, but answering your very question...

You cannot do `new clazz[]` as `new` in Java takes a class name, not an expression which evaluates to a Class object.
More pragmatically: `new String[10]` is not the same as `new String.class[10]`. The latter is what your example does. And is simply not supported.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for [`Array.newInstance(Class<?>, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance(java.lang.Class,%20int))?  That's the way to reflectively build an array with a `Class` object rather than a compile-time type.

You cannot write `new clazz[values.length]`, but you can write `Array.newInstance(clazz, values.length)`.